# Play Store charged twice for my users who bought my Android app before

Tags: android, google-play

I keep receiving complains from my users that Play Store showing price to my users to redownload my Android app even after they bought it.

My user even contacted Google and they said nothing they can do but only me who can fix the problem.

What's exactly happening? This creates a very bad experience for my users.

Comment: I would contact Google about the problem.

Comment: it is not possible. Only if  you have just uploaded it as new app. Any way, your question does not relate to programming.

Comment: @Henry, yup will contact Google once I got the order number from my user. I have a feeling they will reply that they can't do anythign about it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, yea I know right. It's not even possible from developer end. I keep getting complains from users saying me cheating them for charging twice while we did nothing on this. I didn't even upload any new app

Comment: @kkl, sometimes the users are making a new google play accounts (after forgetting old ones), and therefore - not having your app bought on that account. You may ask them to find a google play receipt latter in their email, if they have already bought the app, and go to google support with that receipt

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I did. Not sure if they still keep the receipt. I guess I can only do that to clarify.